# bulk import url rewrite management for products

Tags: magento-1.9, import, products, url-rewrite

Is there an extension, or a way using MAGMI by which I can import a csv containing the URLs and paths I wish to rewrite? Seems customary but I think I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this, because of 404 reports from something like Google Webmaster Tools, you're much better off configuring the webserver to handle those. It prevents core_url_rewrite growing out of proportions and it's quite easy to reformat a 2-column csv with source and target URL to a rewrite for the webserver you're using.